# What is the use of " :: " in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt, and was reading some programs. At some places they have used it to refer to a method and at some keyword. So im confused with what exactly is its use?

```
void CalculatorForm::on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(int value){
     outputWidget->setText(QString::number(value + inputSpinBox2->value()));
 }
```

The above one is a snippet in which a method is used and below one im not getting. So what is exact usage of it and details.

```
#include "ui_widget.h"
 class MyWidget : public QWidget {
 private:
     Ui::MyWidget m_ui;
 };
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's the scope resolution operator and has nothing to do with Qt in particular.

Comment: You should consider using a [search engine](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+two+colons) in the future.

Comment: To put it in plain language: it's a language feature, not Qt feature. Frank is spot on.